# ExactTarget: Efficient way to get list unsubscriber/resubscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, subscriber, unsubscriber

I am using python FuelSDK to retrieve the latest subscribers status for each list.

Currently, I am using the **ModifiedDate** to filter subscribers to only get subscribers who have been modified since last pull.

The problem is if I add a new attribute to the list, the **ModifiedDate** gets updated, so I can't guarantee the **ModifiedDate** only gets updated when the status changed.

Is there a better way to retrieve the latest subscribers status?